# Dynamically set onKeyUp attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently writing a `JS code` to calculate a running total of numeric inputs. The problem I have is that for my actual project I can't change the HTML directly as it is generated from a scripting programme. I can however manipulate it with `JS`.

so far I've got a div to add which can show the sum of the inputs. But this only works if the inputs have an `onKeyUp()` attribute. This isn't true for the generated HTML so I need to write a `JS script` which adds it in. This is what I've done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //try to set an onKeyUp attribute to the elements.
    var number1 = document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q0");
    number1.onkeyup = function(){ return summer()};

    var number2 = document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q1");
    number2.onkeyup = function(){ return summer()};

    var number3 = document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q2");
    number3.onkeyup = function(){ return summer()};

    function summer() {
        var count = 0; //start with nothing
        var num1 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q0").value)) || 0; //if there aren't any numbers, add nothing
        var num2 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q1").value)) || 0;
        var num3 = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("_Q0_Q0_Q2").value)) || 0;
        count = num1+num2+num3; //sum them up
        if (!document.getElementById("output")) { //check to see if there is a div with the output already, if not create one.
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'output');
        var gutterDiv = document.getElementById("right_gutter")
        gutterDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
        };
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Your running total = "+count
}; //show output
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="_Q0_Q0_Q0" name="number" />
<input type="text" id="_Q0_Q0_Q1" name="number" />
<input type="text" id="_Q0_Q0_Q2" name="number" />
<div id='right_gutter'>
<button type="button" onclick="summer()">Clicking here adds your input to the "count" variable</button> //two purposes of this. 1) Acts as a placeholder for where the output should end up. 2) Shows that the summing function works.
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Event handlers are case sensitive, so it should be `onkeyup`.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, so you might see: `<input type="text" onKeyUp="myfunc();" />` but this doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: Changed it to onkeyup but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: You are including the script in the head tag. It will get executed before the DOM is fully ready. Maybe you can use `window.onload` ?

Comment: It's supposed to dynamically change a variable which shows the sum of the numbers the user has entered into the text boxes. The end product should check this summed value against a value given previously to see if they match. (e.g. you said you eat this many meals a week but you've told me you eat x breakfasts, y lunches and z dinners, the sum of which =/= the total)

Comment: window.onload got it working. Thanks! I'm still new to this so don't know a lot of the different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not shure if right but no need for so much code.

js

```
window.onload=function(){
 function sum(){
  result.textContent="Your running total = "+
  ((form.a.value*1)+(form.b.value*1)+(form.c.value*1));
 }
 var form=document.forms[0],result=document.getElementById('result');
 form.addEventListener('keyup',sum,false);
}
```

html

```
<form><input name="a"><input name="b"><input name="c"></form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/cyLaF/

Answer (score 4):

Glad you got it working. I guess this is redundant now but I'm posting this answer in case it is useful anyway.

```
//Create a NodeList of all elements whose name='number':
var nums = document.getElementsByName("number"); 

//add the onkeyup event to all nums:
for(var n=0; n < nums.length; n++){
    nums[n].onkeyup = function(){return summer()};
}

//add the click event to the button:
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){return summer();}


function summer() {
    var count = 0;
    for(var n=0; n < nums.length; n++){//iterate and sum values
        count += parseFloat(nums[n].value) || 0;
    }
    //create the output element:
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output") || document.createElement('div');
    //if it doesnt already exist append it:
    if(!document.getElementById("output")){
            outputDiv.setAttribute('id', 'output');
            document.getElementById("right_gutter").appendChild(outputDiv);
            createdAlready=true;
        }
    //set the output string:
    outputDiv.innerHTML = "Your running total = "+count;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8BrQE/2/